# Woocommerce "/checkout/order-received" page is being indexed by search engines

Tags: woocommerce

I recently found this problem where google indexes the order received page, so customers addresses are exposed to the public.  I've added

```
if(is_checkout()) {
?><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><?php
}
```

Still google has this page indexed.  The url for these pages look like `https://www.domain.co.uk/checkout/order-received/1749/?key=wc_order_5570453459f7`

Shouldn't the order key only be valid for a short while?  I thought of adding a user logged in condition but what if the purchase is by a guest?

How do i solve?  I don't want customers information to be exposed.

Comment: I have a suspicion that Google bot is indexing the order received page, although the bot is quite intelligent it still cannot work out the order number and the key. Is it indexing all the orders on your site? Even if you were to put that meta no-index , what happens in a case where the customer publicly posts the URL of the order on their Facebook or Twitter account or on their blog saying "Hey, look what I just bought", Google will certainly pick that up.

Comment: The `noindex` isn't really going to help all that much, more important is *how* Google is able to find that page to index. Is it being linked to from anywhere? Is it being included in your sitemap?